# Checking for data() in an HTML element both when attached though the Jquery data() and also when attached through data-attributes in the HTML directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery , so just playing around and I am trying to build a small plugin , problem is it will be using the data() attribute extensively . i went through the Jquery doc's a few times . But I have a small problem that persists.

I have the following HTML :

```
    <button data-m='lala' data-l="pinky">Click me</button>
```

and the following Jquery code to check if there's any `data()` attached with the button element .

```
            if ($('button').data()) {
                console.log('there is data');
            }else{
                console.log('Theres no data')
            }
```

but it logs `there is data` even when I take off the html data attributes .

Later I came across a Jquery method that by itself , will tell you if there is `data` attached with the selected element ,the method is called `$.hasData()`.

So I modified my program like below :

```
if ($.hasData($('button'))) {
                    console.log('there is data');
                }else{
                    console.log('Theres no data')
                }
```

Now I get `there's no data` in my console. I don't know whats wrong .

Now to test if this was happening because I was attaching the data through data attributes and not the Jquery `data()` method. I again modified my program to something as follows :

```
$('button').data({
                      'lala'   : '1',
                      'lala-1' :  '2'
                });

                if ($.hasData($('button'))) {
                    console.log('there is data');
                }else{
                    console.log('Theres no data')
                }
```

I still get `Theres no data` in my console.

but if I console.log the below :

```
console.log($('button').data());
```

i get :

```
{ lala: "1", lala-1: "2", m: "lala", l: "pinky" }
```

Now all I want is my code to tell me when a given element has data attached to it (both direct html data attributes and also though the Jquery `data()` attribute) or no data attached to it .

I would appreciate any help , explanation or even if somebody could point me in the right direction .

Thank you .

Alexander.

Comment: You `hasData()` is not working because you need to pass a dom element reference not a jQuery object to that...

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks , i am more concerned about `if ($('button').data())` not working though .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that JQuery's 'hasData' takes an element, and not a collection of elements.

Try:

```
var button = jQuery('button')[0];
jQuery.data( button, "testing", 123 );

if (jQuery.hasData(button)) {
  console.log('there is data');
} else {
  console.log('Theres no data')
}
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.hasdata/

Edit:

After testing I got some similar results with hasData not picking up element data attributes, so this little work around works good for me:

HTML:

```
<button id="a" data-m='lala' data-l="pinky">Click me</button>  
<button id="b">Click me</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var buttonA = jQuery('#a');
var buttonB = jQuery('#b');

if (Object.keys(buttonA.data()).length >0) {
    console.log("buttonA", "Has data");
} else {
    console.log("buttonA", "Has no data");
}
if (Object.keys(buttonB.data()).length >0) {
    console.log("buttonB", "Has data");
} else {
    console.log("buttonB", "Has no data");
}
```

Output:

```
buttonA Has data
buttonB Has no data
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `.data()` will always return an object (even an empty one - `{}`) therefore using it in an `if` condition as you are will always result in `true`.

The `$.hasData` method accepts a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so the correct syntax for its use in your case would be this:

```
if ($.hasData($('button')[0])) {
    console.log('there is data');
} else {
    console.log('Theres no data')
}
```

The `[0]` after the selector is used to retrieve the first item in the jQuery object - the DOMElement itself.

Comment: I was actually more keen on checking using the data() attribute(because this plugin does the same https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L280 .. see line 280 and 283 ) , so if i have to make a check using only the data attibute i gotta do something like : `$('button').data(key value goes here)` .

Comment: That code is using the `data()` method to retrieve an individual data value. That will return a string, which can be used in an if condition as an empty string = false. To summarise, `data()` return an object, `data('property-name')` returns a string.

Comment: Thanks , and thats why i guess the check on line 284(https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L284) ?? . anyways , quite enlightening . Thanks a ton . but will be accepting D's answer as he asnwered first. TY again .